# Intents crashing in simple android game

Tags: java, android, android-intent, methods, extras

I am making a simple game for android, however as I am kind of beginner sometimes I have some problems with basic things and errors in my code. I dont know what is wrong with that code but it seems to crash when I press back button and does not redirect the score from game to main menu.

```
public void finish(){
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("GAME_SCORE",gameView.getHitCount());
    setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    super.finish();
  }
```

GameView:

```
public int getHitCount(){
    return hitCount;
    }
```

and MainMenu:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent retIntent) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == SCORE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (retIntent.hasExtra("GAME_SCORE")) {
                int scoreFromGame = retIntent.getExtras().getInt("GAME_SCORE");
                tvScore.setText(""+Integer.toString(scoreFromGame));
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace please?

Comment: How can I do it? I'm sorry but as I said I am still at the early stage of learning :)

Comment: post your logCat as an image -> take a screen shot of your full logCat and Edit your question

Comment: does your game activity returns you to main menu ?

Comment: I have now added the LogCat screenshots to the description

Answer (score 2):

from what I've understand, the `GameActivity` returns the user to `mainMenuActivity` so first thing first the `super` keyword in java comes always first you can't just put anything before `super()` and if the game activity returns you to main menu the `onFinish()` method must be:

```
super.finish();
Intent returnIntent = new Intent(GameActivity.this,MainMenu.class);
returnIntent.putExtra("GAME_SCORE",gameView.getHitCount());
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
```

and to get the game score if its integer then use:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int intValue = intent.getIntExtra("GAME_SCORE", 0);
```

in your `MainMenu` class
hope this will help you.

Comment: Ahmad is right. In the code in the question, you're saying make a new Intent but not sending it anything. You need to send it the sending activity and receiving activity as Ahmad has stated here.

Comment: It helped with the activity to return to main menu once the back button is pressed and it does not crash now, but when it comes to the game score where certainly should I put the above code?

Comment: okay first in main menu define gameScore as an instance variable inside the class and before onCreate then use getIntent() inside onCreate() and initialize gameScore using the code above then use the variable where you desire

Comment: delete setResult() from your onFinish() and add startActivity(intent); then use get intent like i've mintioned before in your onCreate and delete the method onActivityResult() or other SOL: use onActivityResult but you must use startActivityForResult in your onFinish()